# AWS Free Usage Tier + Cloudflare... possible?

Tags: amazon-ec2, performance, amazon-web-services, cloudflare

If I throw my MySQL/PHP app up on a Amazon EC2 instance (using their AWS Free Usage Tier program) and couple it with CloudFlare (the free plan of course) roughly how many daily visitors can I comfortably handle before performance starts to suffer? Just looking for a rough estimate or educated guess - I understand this setup might be less than ideal but I'm still very curious nonetheless.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on how much your app is cached at CloudFlare. I ran some basic tests a while back (for something completly different) and a micro instance in the US, running Varnish, with a WordPress server in the backend (in Germany) was able to handle 50 users at a time, and was not breaking a sweat. the German Server only had to respond to the Varnish box once. I used [LoadImpact](http://loadimpact.com/) to do the testing...

If you can get your site to return fairly static pages, with a fairly long expiration date, it should stay in CloudFlare for a fair amount of time. your mileage may vary though.